# Select multiple values and return values based on individual comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write a query that selects multiple values from a table and compares two of them. The larger one should be used.

example:

| TagName | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 20 |
| A2 | 30 |
| A3-1 | 15 |
| A3-2 | 20 |

I want A3-2 the result table as:

| TagName | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 20 |
| A2 | 30 |
| A3 | 20 |

How would I do that?
Unfortunately, I have to do this comparison in SQL

Thank you :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If you revert the latest edit, you can find you need an empty row before the table format.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using ssms
the query will be run in the microsoft report builder

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `MAX` with `LEFT` function :

```
select distinct LEFT(TagName, 2) as IDs, max(valuee) over (partition by (LEFT(TagName, 2)))
from tablee
order by IDs ASC
```

[HERE is fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dbcdc/1) but for posgresql, but it should work for you too, if not, at least this logic can be used

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided an example that corresponds to how the data looks in real life, you could try something like:

```
select substring(TagName, 1, 2) as TagName, max(Value) as Value from table group by TagName
```

This way you create a substring that will include all of the values from similar records, compare them & display the maximum one.